# Group values by task and keep progress as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by

I'm trying to organize tasks based on a task description (so that I can later accomplish the average of their progress

```
    let ar = [
  [
    { task: 'Hello world', c: 56 },
    { task: 'Hello world1', c: 34 },
    { task: 'Hello world2', c: 80 },
    { task: 'Hello world3', c: 80 },
  ],
  [
    { task: 'Hello world', c: 12 },
    { task: 'Hello world1', c: 60 },
    { task: 'Hello world2', c: 90 },
  ],
];
let t = [
  { task: 'Hello world', c: [56, 12] },
  { task: 'Hello world1', c: [34, 60] },
  { task: 'Hello world2', c: [80, 90] },
  { task: 'Hello world3', c: [80] },
];
```

**ar** is the original one and the **t** is the one that I would like to end up with

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group elements by the `task` value using `Array.prototype.reduce`.

And using `Array.prototype.flat`, you can create 1d array with all sub-array  elements concatenated into it

```js
let input = [
  [
    { task: 'Hello world', c: 56 },
    { task: 'Hello world1', c: 34 },
    { task: 'Hello world2', c: 80 },
    { task: 'Hello world3', c: 80 },
  ],
  [
    { task: 'Hello world', c: 12 },
    { task: 'Hello world1', c: 60 },
    { task: 'Hello world2', c: 90 },
  ],
];

const groupBy = input.flat().reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.task] ? acc[cur.task].c.push(cur.c) : acc[cur.task] = {
    task: cur.task,
    c: [ cur.c ]
  };
  return acc;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(groupBy);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant answer :)